# When will the series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the following serises

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{h}{4}\right)^n \frac{(2n)!\times (2n)!}{n! \times n!\times n! }.
\end{align}
What condition should be imposed on $h$ to guarantee the covergence? Any idea is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: first thing you should check is when the general term goes to $0$ as $n\rightarrow +\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Ratio Test, and letting $a_n=\left(\frac{h}{4}\right)^n \frac{(2n)!\times (2n)!}{n! \times n!\times n! }$,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|\\
=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|\left ( \frac{h}{4} \right )\frac{(2n+1)^2 (2n+2)^2}{(n+1)^3}\right|\\
=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|h\frac{(2n+1)^2}{(n+1)}\right|,$$
which very obviously diverges for any value of $h$ other than $h=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and it helps a lot.